# Error during conversion from provided DBF input charset to UTF-8, PHP SHAPEFILE

Tags: php, shapefile

I'm using the lib, gasparesganga/php-shapefile, to read a shapefile.

```
public static function getShapefile(string $url): ?ShapefileReader
    {
        $shapefile = null;
        $tmp = Utils::tempdir(prefix: 'icmbio_');
        $fileName = ZIP::getFrom($url, $tmp);

        ZIP::extractTo($fileName, $tmp);

        $content = Utils::readDir($tmp);

        if (!empty($content)) {
            $basename = pathinfo(reset($content), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $path = "$tmp/$basename";

            $shapefile = new ShapefileReader($path);
        }

        Utils::closeDir($tmp);

        return $shapefile;
    }
```

In this case I'm just unzipping a folder with shp, shx, dbf, qmd, prj, cpg files.

and when I read the file, the following error occurs:

```
#message: "Error during conversion from provided DBF input charset to UTF-8"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/vendor/gasparesganga/php-shapefile/src/Shapefile/ShapefileReader.php"
  #line: 335
  -error_type: "ERR_DBF_CHARSET_CONVERSION"
```

Passing the flag [Shapefile::OPTION_IGNORE_FILE_DBF => true],
The data is now missing, but without any errors.
Is there anything in the documentation that I might not have found about BDF options to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Only need pass options to false, when DBF is not UFT-8 charset

```
   [
       Shapefile::OPTION_DBF_CONVERT_TO_UTF8_DEFAULT => false,
       Shapefile::OPTION_DBF_CONVERT_TO_UTF8 => false
   ]
```